# Split audio file into multiple files using ffmpeg on macOS

Tags: unix, audio, ffmpeg

My idea was to save some time and split long audio file into multiple audio files and reading the data (startTime, endTime, artist, title) from a text file.
Using terminal on MacOS (UNIX) and ffmpeg (audio).

Input put file example with 3 lines:

```
00:00 - 06:16 - art - tit
06:16 - 09:22 - arti - titl
09:22 - 13:13 - artist - title
```

My unix code, shell file: "split.command"

```
inputFileName=audiofile
input=test.txt


while IFS= read -r var
do

startTime=$(echo "$var" | cut -f1 -d"-")
endTime=$(echo "$var" | cut -f2 -d"-")
artist=$(echo "$var" | cut -f3 -d"-")
title=$(echo "$var" | cut -f4 -d"-")

echo ffmpeg -i ~/Downloads/$inputFileName.mp3 -metadata artist="$artist" -metadata title="$title" -ss $startTime -to $endTime -acodec copy "$title".mp3 -vsync 2

wait 

done < "$input"
```

When I ECHO it, everything looks fine.

```
$ sh split.command
ffmpeg -i /Users/tony/Downloads/audiofile.mp3 -metadata artist= art  -metadata title= tit -ss 00:00 -to 06:16 -acodec copy  tit.mp3 -vsync 2
ffmpeg -i /Users/tony/Downloads/audiofile.mp3 -metadata artist= arti  -metadata title= titl -ss 06:16 -to 09:22 -acodec copy  titl.mp3 -vsync 2
ffmpeg -i /Users/tony/Downloads/audiofile.mp3 -metadata artist= artist  -metadata title= title -ss 09:22 -to 13:13 -acodec copy  title.mp3 -vsync 2
```

When ECHO is deleted, it should work as command. The first audio is fine, the second throws an error, and the third work but has missing artwork .

```
1st *works*
2nd *error* Invalid duration specification for to: arti
3rd *works but..* [mp3 @ 0x7ff7e1800000] No packets were sent for some of the attached pictures.
```

Comment: Did the answer fix your problem?

Comment: @Inian I tried the code below, same result, slightly different error at "2nd": `Invalid duration specification for ss:  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two major problems, the first with spaces when reading the file and the second was with the spaces at the output name. Here it first converts all the properties to a string and then it all proccess via ffmpeg.

```
read input        

inputFileName=$input
mkdir $input    
inputText=${inputFileName}.txt
i=0

function toString {
while IFS=- read -r startTime endTime artist title3; do
((i++))
title2="${title3// }"

str[i]=$(echo " -i "$PWD"/"${inputFileName}".mp3 -metadata artist="${artist// }" -metadata title="${title2// }" -ss "${startTime// }" -to "${endTime// }" -acodec copy "$input/${title2}".mp3 -vsync 2 ")
done< "$inputText"
}

function toSplit {
for j in $(seq 1 $i);
do
    ffmpeg ${str[$j]}
done
}

toString
toSplit
```

On macOS it works only in terminal:

```
sh file.command
```

It does not work when used as executable file!