# Python, ffmpeg split list of audio files

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I know how to split **one** single audio file with python and ffmpeg:

```
command = "ffmpeg -i a.wav -f segment -segment_time 60 -c copy out_dir/output%09d.wav"
command = shlex.split(command)
subprocess.run(command)
```

For my current task, I have a list of several hundred `.wav` files I want to split.

My current solution is:

```py
def parse_and_split_dir(directory, out_dir):
  files = [x for x in os.listdir(directory) if ".wav" in x]
  print(files)
  cntr = 0
  for wav in files:
    wav = wav.replace(" ", "\ ")
    temp_dir = os.path.join(out_dir, str(cntr))
    Path(temp_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    temp_dir = os.path.join(temp_dir, "output%05d.wav")
    command = "ffmpeg -i {} -f segment -segment_time 60 -c copy {}".format(os.path.join(directory, wav), temp_dir)
    command = shlex.split(command)
    subprocess.run(command)
    cntr += 1
```

I list all .wav files, and for each file I create a directory where I store the split files into. This implies that file naming start with index 1 for each new file.
E.g. folder 1 contains files `...1.wav` to `...9.wav`, folder 2 contains `...1.wav` to `...13.wav` and so on.

In short, I ideally want to parse the whole directory with a single command, while keeping the naming continually from file to file, e.g. when the last wav saved its last split with `...10.split`, the next split for the next file should be saved as `..11.split`.

I thought about first concatenating all the single files to one file, and then splitting them again (which introduces massive overhead), and unnecessarily consumes memory and disk space. An alternative I thought of was using a *.wav wildcard, but ffmpeg found no file called `*.wav`(which is expected).

Related question: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542298/split-audio-file-into-multiple-files-using-ffmpeg-on-macos)

Comment: Hi. Could you help me out with FFMPEG on python. I am facing some issues in audio splitting. For a single file.

Comment: @Adideva98, just open a question, describe your problem in detail, and we can look into it. Leave the link to the opened question here, so I can find it.

Comment: Hey. This is the link to my question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099145/issues-in-python-based-ffmpeg-operation?noredirect=1#comment120360961_68099145