# Issues in python based ffmpeg operation

Tags: python, loops, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to write a script that would automatically take duration values and chop an audio file into smaller splits. To do this I have saved all my start times and durations in a list. And this is the code I am trying to run.

```
for k in range(0,len(start_time)):
  s=start_time[k]
  e=Duration[k]
  filename = "output%d.mp3" % (k)
  !ffmpeg -i Audio.mp3 -ss s -t e -acodec copy filename
  k=k+1
```

On running this I get the following error
`Invalid duration specification for ss: s`
I suspect that this error arises because of the fact that since I am using lists to call elements, the time stamp comes with quotes on both sides. Secondly, I am not sure how to specify the filename, such that each created split has the name of this format Output_1.mp3 and so on. The integer will be an identifier of the split. What could be possible fixes for this piece of code? Please note that I am running this on Google Colab.

Comment: How does `s` look like ?

Comment: This is a typical value from the strat_time list which becomes s in this case. ```00:00:50.899000``` . I suspect there are quotes around it which is meddling with ffmpeg

Comment: The `!` syntax is not a Python command, it's a feature of the interpreter. You should use the `subprocess` library instead.

Answer (score 1):

Google Colab is running Jupyter notebook powered by [IPython](https://ipython.org/) in its cloud, IPython uses special syntax for shell invocation (commands starting from **!** exclamation mark), i.e. they are executed in (temporary) [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) session. In case of Google Colab it's [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/):

```
res = !echo $SHELL
print(res)
> ['/bin/bash']
```

As I checked, ffmpeg is indeed available on Google Colab:

```
res = !which ffmpeg
print(res)
> ['/usr/bin/ffmpeg']
```

, so you have legitimate error message printed by ffmpeg: *"Invalid duration specification ... "* (I mean not by shell or python) and it just means that variable you're passing is not substituted with its value the way you do. And it's so because this above mentioned special syntax is not followed for passing variable *to* the shell, check [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html#Passing-Values-to-and-from-the-Shell); variables should be curly-braced to be passed:

```
!ffmpeg -i Audio.mp3 -ss {s} -t {e} -acodec copy {filename}
```